# Internet over Ethernet: DNS works, internet doesn't (Windows works, Linux doesn't)

Tags: networking

I have a PC connected to the Internet using an Ethernet connection. Using Ubuntu I am able to resolve domains using nslookup, but if I try to open an internet page, or use wget it doesn't work.

I have used Arch Linux, Mint and Ubuntu Live on two netbooks, all of them unsuccessfully. Windows, however, works just fine.

**ifconfig:**

```
sudo ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:18:80:79:18  
          inet addr:10.20.6.180  Bcast:10.20.7.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:18ff:fe80:7918/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:17
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:659976 (659.9 KB)  TX bytes:253881 (253.8 KB)
          Interrupt:40
```

**route:**

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.20.6.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.20.6.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.20.6.1       0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
```

**netstat:**

```
netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.20.6.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.20.6.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.20.6.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

**iptables:**

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**resolv.conf:**

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf 
search uni-mannheim.de 
nameserver 134.155.96.51 
nameserver 134.155.96.53
```

**tracepath is not working:**

```
sudo tracepath www.google.com
 1:  laptop.local                                          0.342ms pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
```

**/etc/host.conf**

```
sudo cat /etc/host.conf
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
sudo cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**nslookup google.com**

```
nslookup google.com
Server:     134.155.96.51
Address:    134.155.96.51#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.39.104
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.39.105
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.39.106
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.39.147
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.39.99
Name:   google.com
Address: 74.125.39.103
```

**wget google.com**

```
wget google.com
--2011-08-17 11:05:01--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com... 74.125.39.99, 74.125.39.103, 74.125.39.104, ...
Connecting to google.com|74.125.39.99|:80...
```

**dig google.com**

tracepath doesn't work but dig does

```
dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2643
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     175 IN  A   74.125.39.103
google.com.     175 IN  A   74.125.39.104
google.com.     175 IN  A   74.125.39.105
google.com.     175 IN  A   74.125.39.106
google.com.     175 IN  A   74.125.39.147
google.com.     175 IN  A   74.125.39.99

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     104161  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     104161  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     104161  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     104161  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     277325  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     277325  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     277325  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     277325  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 134.155.96.51#53(134.155.96.51)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 17 11:06:14 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 260
```

Comment: Can we see your windows routing table?. You can use `route print` on the command shell to retrieve it.

Comment: Can this be a firewall related issue? try stopping the Ubuntu's firewall and let's see what happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My German is really rusty (been 20 years ...), but based on [this information](http://ncc.uni-mannheim.de/index.php?id1=193&id2=200) and if you're indeed using uni-mannheim.de network, you need to instruct your software to use their proxy (or just use their vpn). To verify, try

```
echo "http_proxy = http://www-cache.uni-mannheim.de:3128/" | sudo tee -a /etc/wgetrc
echo "use_proxy = on" | sudo tee -a /etc/wgetrc
wget http://www.google.com/
```

If this works, you should perhaps use the provided vpn connection instead (it probably supports more protocols). Alternatively, you have to instruct all relevant software to use this proxy.

Don't forget to remove those two lines from `/etc/wgetrc` once you're done with the testing.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you! I still don't understand why windows manages to autoconfigure the proxy while linux gets stuck...
Thank you for your time!